# How to make this code DRYer

Tags: java, exception, dry

So I have a generated class (`PartnerConnection`) that provides DML operations to the SalesForce cloud platform.  We were having issues where our long running integration process was failing due to connection issues with either SalesForce or the system running the code.

In order to solve this issue, I extended the `PartnerConnection` class with what I name an `AdvancedPartnerConnection`.  The `AdvancedPartnerConnection` just **overrides** the methods of the `PartnerConnection` and wraps them with **try/catch/retry** logic.

```
@Override
public QueryResult query(String queryString) throws ConnectionException{
    int attempt = 0;
    ConnectionException lastException = null;
    while(true){
        if(attempt < maxAttempts){ //maxAttempts constant
            if(lastException != null){
                try {
                    //exponentially increase wait times
                    Long sleepTime =(long) Math.pow(sleepBase, attempt) * 300;
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // something bad has happen, throw the connection exception
                    throw lastException;
                }
            }
            attempt ++;
            try{
                //call super class method
                return super.query(queryString);
            }catch(ConnectionException e){
                lastException = e;
            }
        }else{
            throw lastException;
        }
    }
}
```

I've implemented this for a handful of the super class methods and **the only difference is the method being called and its' parameters**. It has become a real pain if I decided to change any of the retry logic as I want it to be consistent across all methods.

Does anyone have a way I could extract the retry logic into a separate class or method and maybe pass in the function call?  I've done stuff like this in .NET but I'm not sure how to do it in java.

Comment: The signature of the `PartnerConnection` class? It's your code ?

Comment: The PartnerConnection is not my code.

Comment: Does PartnerConnection implement any interface?

Comment: no, its just a regular class.  Extending it actually worked well, because I was able to swap the PartnerConnection with a AdvancedPartnerConnection and didn't have to change any code using the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to capture all calls to all object methods and apply some logic to all of them.
 You could create a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and retry in the [handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) invoke method.

With this approach based on the method signature you decide what to do.

Another approaches could use `AspectJ` or any other `AOP` framework, but your use case is very simple to add that kind of dependencies, IMO.

If the class which you want to add some `behaviour` is not yours then this solution might not be the most elegant. But if you are willing to sacrifice some elegance to gain maintainability (since you are not replicating code) then you could:

```
class NotYourClass {
    public void voidMethod() {}
    public int intMethod(int n) { return 0; }
}
```

To create a `proxy` you must create an `interface` with all the methods of the class. This is the crappy part, but this do not add any dependency to your application.

```
interface YourInterface {
    public void voidMethod();
    public int intMethod(int n);
}
```

Next thing you need is an `InvocationHandler` that will contain the `behavior`.

```
class YourInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final NotYourClass target;

    public YourInvocationHandler(NotYourClass target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
                // Here you must look to the methods that are the ones that you want.
                return method..invoke(target, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Retry?
            method.invoke(target, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind that this is from the top of my head. But should be something along those lines.

If creating that interface is something unnacceptable for you then you can look at some `AOP` frameworks.

Comment: if you have some extra time could you add a code example of how this would work?

Comment: Thanks, but why do I need to implement "YourInterface"?  Ideally I would just use the invocation handler to encapsulate the retry logic and then have an instance of it inside the AdvancedPartnerConnection which I use in each override.  Creating an interface isn't really an option because the PartnerConnection is generated code in a third party library that could eventually be updated.

Comment: unfortunately I wasn't able to use a InvocationHandler but Method.Invoke turned out to be helpful.